# Find missing month after grouping with dplyr

Tags: r, dplyr, missing-data

I have a data frame with two columns that I am grouping by with `dplyr`, a column of months (as numerics, e.g. 1 through 12), and several columns with statistical data following that (values unimportant). An example:

```
ID_1   ID_2   month  st1    st2
1      1      1      0.5    0.2
1      1      2      0.7    0.9
1      1      3      1.1    1.7
1      1      4      2.6    0.8
1      1      5      1.8    1.3
1      1      6      2.1    2.2
1      1      7      0.5    0.2
1      1      8      0.7    0.9
1      1      9      1.1    1.7
1      1      10     2.6    0.8
1      1      11     1.8    1.3
1      1      12     2.1    2.2
1      2      1      0.5    0.2
1      2      2      0.7    0.9
1      2      3      1.1    1.7
1      2      4      2.6    0.8
1      2      5      1.8    1.3
1      2      6      2.1    2.2
1      2      7      0.5    0.2
1      2      9      1.1    1.7
1      2      10     2.6    0.8
1      2      11     1.8    1.3
1      2      12     2.1    2.2
```

For the second grouping (`ID_1 = 1` and `ID_2 = 2`), there is a month missing from the data (`month = 8`). Is there a way I can find this month and insert a *row* with the correct `ID_1` and `ID_2` values, the missing `month` value, and `NA` values for the rest of the columns? I've been playing around with this using `dplyr` functions and can't seem to figure it out, perhaps there is even a non-`dplyr` solution out there as well.

PS: If it helps, each unique grouping of `ID_1` and `ID_2` will have no more than 1 month missing.

Comment: its not clear to me what you're looking for. You really want a whole new column just to show the value of the missing month? What would be the other values of the column for the other months that werent missing -would they be NA?

Comment: My wording is off in my post, I've edited it. I want to insert a new **row** where the missing month should be, with the columns of that new row populated with `NA` (aside from the ID columns).

Answer (score 7, accepted):

This can be done via `tidyr::complete`:

```
library(dplyr)
library(tidyr)

dat %>% 
    group_by(ID_1, ID_2) %>%
    complete(month = 1:12)
```

Tail of dataset:

```
Source: local data frame [6 x 5]
Groups: ID_1, ID_2 [1]

   ID_1  ID_2 month   st1   st2
  <int> <int> <int> <dbl> <dbl>
1     1     2     7   0.5   0.2
2     1     2     8    NA    NA
3     1     2     9   1.1   1.7
4     1     2    10   2.6   0.8
5     1     2    11   1.8   1.3
6     1     2    12   2.1   2.2
```

Answer (score 7):

Expand grid to make all combos of groups, then merge:

```
# make reference with all needed rows
ref <- data.frame(expand.grid(unique(df1$ID_1),
                              unique(df1$ID_2),
                              1:12))
colnames(ref) <- colnames(df1)[1:3]

# them merge with all TRUE
res <- merge(df1, ref, all = TRUE)

# to check output, show only month = 8
res[ res$month == 8, ]
#    ID_1 ID_2 month st1 st2
# 8     1    1     8 0.7 0.9
# 20    1    2     8  NA  NA
```

Answer (score 3):

If you go with `tidyr`, there is the `complete` function for this, you can nest `ID_1` and `ID_2` if you want both of the two variables as your grouping variable:

```
library(tidyr)
df1 = df %>% complete(nesting(ID_1, ID_2), month)

tail(df1)    
# Source: local data frame [6 x 5]

#    ID_1  ID_2 month   st1   st2
#   <int> <int> <int> <dbl> <dbl>
# 1     1     2     7   0.5   0.2
# 2     1     2     8    NA    NA
# 3     1     2     9   1.1   1.7
# 4     1     2    10   2.6   0.8
# 5     1     2    11   1.8   1.3
# 6     1     2    12   2.1   2.2
```